# Cannot get parent class property in struts.xml redirect action

Tags: java, url, inheritance, struts2, parameter-passing

My `actionA` class extends `theParent` class.

I have a struts.xml which will redirect from `actionA` to `someOtherAction`
like this:

```xml
<action name="actionA" class="my.path.actionA">
        ...
    <result type="redirect-action" name="performRedirect">
        <param name="actionName">someOtherAction</param>
        <param name="parse">true</param>
        <param name="id">${id}</param>
    </result>   
</action>
```

My `actionA` has no property named `Id`.

In my parent class `theParent` there is  a parameter named `id` with a public getter and setter. My parent class is an abstract class.

When the redirect is performed, `id` gets assigned a long value like:

```
myparent.groupId.of.maven%thisProject-war%3Awar%blabla
```

I know that I can solve this by simply creating a getter in my `actionA` class which returns the `id` of the parent.

I wonder though why this happens and if there is a better way to fix this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: The question is not clear; what type is `id` ? Which version of struts2 are you using, since spinal case (`redirect-action`) has been deprecated **a lot** of versions ago ?

Comment: It's a long value like private Long id; 
I am using an old version 2.0.14

Comment: So your `id` field in the URL is `myparent.groupId.of.maven%thisProject-war%3Awar%blabla` ? How can a long return something like that ?

Comment: yes my id parameter of the url gets assigned this weird value..that is exactly my question: if anyone has an idea why this happens. I am circumventing the problem by creating a getter in actionA which returns the id from theParent like public Long getParentId (){return super.getId();} And of course I rename my url parameter to parentId.

Comment: Please post the code of the methods